# Can i set up sql server as master and my sql as slave in replication

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, replication

Can i set up sql server as master and my sql as slave in replication?
I can find only two subscriber ie.Oracle Subscribers and IBM DB2 Subscribers. how to add my sql>??? –

Edit

Sorry for not asking question properly,See we will be getting sql server backup from client every night,and we have to load it to my sql every night.so we my solution is t0 try transtional replication.so i am trying heterogenous subscriber as my sql and provider as sql server 2000/2008 ..so My question is

```
1>how to make my sql as a heterogenous subscriber
 2>does heterogenous subscribe is possible in sql server 2000.
----------------------------
```

Comment: Publisher and subscriber I presume? Could be done, whats your question?

Comment: yes....pulisher as master and subscriber as slave

Comment: I can find only two subscriber ie.Oracle Subscribers and IBM DB2 Subscribers. how to add my sql>???

Answer (score 0):

According to this you may be out of luck http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151864.aspx